# Security problem when creating a scheduled task

Tags: vb.net, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

To create a scheduled class, I call the `schtasks` command from my code, passing it the necessary arguments. Yet, I can't really figure out how to create a task without the user having to input his password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works by specifying `/RU SYSTEM`